# SQL Query in MS ACCESS to calculate averaged days depending on multiple criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following table in MS Access 2007:

```
customer | Promotion |  Month   | activator | request_date | activation_date
   1     |   promo1  |   10     |   shop1   |  11/10/2011  |   21/10/2011  
   2     |   promo2  |   9      |   shop1   |  10/09/2011  |   15/09/2011  
   3     |   promo2  |   9      |   shop2   |  10/09/2011  |   16/09/2011
   4     |   promo1  |   10     |   shop1   |  12/10/2011  |   13/10/2011
```

What I need is a query to calculate the average number of days that each shop takes to activate each  promotion grouped by month. So for example one result would be:

shop1 in October took an average of 10+1/2 days to activate promo1.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT activator, Month, Promotion, AVG(activation_date - request_date)
FROM ...
GROUP BY activator, Month, Promotion
```

Comment: Hey Marc,
thanks but I get Run-time error '3464': Data type mismatch in criteria expression. 
Probably due to the date difference? I tried avg(datediff()) too but with no luck. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Are those dates date/datetime fields, or char/varchar?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

select

```
  activator,
   [month], 
   promotion, 
   avg(convert( float, datediff(DAY, request_date,activation_date))) as avgTime
```

from dbo.Table1

group by activator,[month], promotion